# Selecting array of strings with SwiftyJSON

Tags: arrays, swift, swifty-json

I am parsing some JSON data using the Swift framework SwiftyJSON. Normally I can select an element such as `domain` from the sample JSON below by doing:

```
json["domain"].string!
```

This works fine, however when selecting the `gallery` element, I am getting a response that it is `nil` when using `json["gallery"].array`

This appears to be an array of strings but perhaps there is something I am misunderstanding. How is it that I can select this element from the JSON sample?

```
{
    "id": 2450,
    "domain": "http://website.com",
    "gallery": [
        "image1",
        "image2",
        "image3"
    ],
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to case your gallery as an array of String.

```
let array = json["gallery"].arrayValue
dump(array)
```

Comment: This gives the following compiler warning `Cast from 'JSON' to unrelated type '[String]' always fails` and also returns `nil`

Comment: @William Updated